# Navigate to a custom component based on a button state

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I've made a toggle button for Login and Register. I want to navigate to the respective components as per this buttons toggle state.

How do I pass or route my custom component inside the condition?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { templateJitUrl } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Demo';

  public show: boolean = false;
  public buttonName: any = 'Register';

  toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;

    if(this.show) {
      this.buttonName = "Login";
      console.log(this.buttonName);
      // code to load login component

    }
    else {
      this.buttonName = "Register";
      console.log(this.buttonName)
      // code to load register component
    }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <button (click)="toggle()" id="bt" routerLink="/register">{{buttonName}}</button>
     </div>
     <br />

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share code of your HTML page as well

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you want to lazy load your components? I have a feeling that you really only want to *show* different states of your app, which really wouldn't require this approach

Comment: Check updated post. @eduPeeth

Comment: @Jens Habegger I want to toggle button for Register/Login and load components accordingly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your motivation behind this approach?

Comment: @Jens Habegger We have to convert webpages into Angular 4. I'm a newbie here so doing things step by step in order to implement the same concept thereafter.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've edited your question to better reflect the difference between loading (which means the component is only actually requested from the server when it is needed) and navigation. Best of luck on your project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use angular `Router` to naviagte to routes. As you are navigating based on a condition it's easy when you use `Router` instead `routerLink` in the template.

```
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <button (click)="toggle()" id="bt">{{buttonName}}</button>
     </div>
     <br />

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
</html>
```

In **component.ts** Import the `Router` and inject it into your component.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


constructor(private router: Router) {

}

toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;

    if(this.show) {
      this.buttonName = "Login";
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);

    }
    else {
      this.buttonName = "Register";
      this.router.navigate(['/register']);
    }
}
```